# 3d Perspective projection is not quite right. (test program in vb6 without using graphics libraries)

Tags: 3d, perspective

I've written a bit of code to plot a cube in 3d with perspective projection.

I can vary the rotation, camera and eye positions.

The resulting plot looks ok but it appears to over stretch at some points in the rotation.

![cube ok on left but distorts during rotation on right][1]

```
    'array containing cube points
box(0, 0) = 500
box(0, 1) = 500
box(0, 2) = 500

box(1, 0) = 1000
box(1, 1) = 500
box(1, 2) = 500

box(2, 0) = 1000
box(2, 1) = 1000
box(2, 2) = 500

box(3, 0) = 500
box(3, 1) = 1000
box(3, 2) = 500

box(4, 0) = 500
box(4, 1) = 1000
box(4, 2) = 1000

box(5, 0) = 500
box(5, 1) = 500
box(5, 2) = 1000

box(6, 0) = 1000
box(6, 1) = 500
box(6, 2) = 1000

box(7, 0) = 1000
box(7, 1) = 1000
box(7, 2) = 1000

'centre of rotation
crx = 750
cry = 750
crz = 750




'eye position   ez needs to be a long way out of the screen
ex = 0
ey = 0
ez = 1000

'angle of rotation
ax = 0
ay = 0
az = 0

'camera position
cx = 0
cy = 0
cz = 0

For f = 0 To 7

'subract centre of rotation to put cube at origin
px = box(f, 0) - crx
py = box(f, 1) - cry
pz = box(f, 2) - crz


'perspective computation
dx = Cos(ay) * (Sin(az) * (py - cy) + Cos(az) * (px - cx)) - Sin(ay) * (pz - cz)
dy = Sin(ax) * (Cos(ay) * (pz - cz) + Sin(ay) * (Sin(az) * (py - cy) + Cos(az) * px)) + Cos(ax) * (Cos(az) * (py - cy) - Sin(az) * (px - cx))
dz = Cos(ax) * (Cos(ay) * (pz - cz) + Sin(ay) * (Sin(az) * (py - cy) + Cos(az) * px)) - Sin(ax) * (Cos(az) * (py - cy) - Sin(az) * (px - cx))

'put new points back to orginal position
dx = dx + crx
dy = dy + cry
dz = dz + crz

'3d to 2d
box2d(f, 0) = ((ez / dz) * dx) - ex
box2d(f, 1) = ((ez / dz) * dy) - ey

next
```

Any ideas?
I'm prototyping the code in vb before moving it onto arduino.
it seems very close, but maybe there's something not quite right with the camera or eye positions...

Comment: Further experimentation showed it was my camera and eye z positons where causing too much perspective correction.

Comment: Further experimentation showed it was my camera and eye z positions where causing too much perspective correction. My current problem is making the cube rotate about it's center. I subtract the position of the middle of the cube to put it at the origin, do he perspective function and add the position back on. I find the middle by taking the mid point between two opposite corners. The centre of the cube is computed every frame. For some reason at certain positions I get a feedback loop and the cube goes haywire...